# Why does razor wrap ' characters inside " characters automatically?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have markup like this

```
<input ... @(Model.SomeID != -1 ? "style='display:none'" : "") />
```

while I'm expecting this result

```
<input ... style='display:none' />
```

oddly I'm getting this

```
<input ... style="'display:none'" />
```

and in the first if I supply the input like this

```
<input ... @(Model.SomeID != -1 ? "style=display:none" : "") />
```

I will get

```
<input ... style="display:none" />  -> my goal
```

But why does razor act like this?

Answer (score 1):

This is not razor feature, this is browser feature. Write it as pure html and test it. You will get the same result.

For example write following

```
<div style=display:none>example</div>
```

your output will looks like following

```
<div style="display:none">example</div>
```

so razor does not add qouates automatically...